# Maven resources plugin exclude not working

Tags: maven

below is my implementation of the resources plugin in my maven build.
according to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html this config should be good but it seems to be ignoring the excludes stanza.  I only want properties files to be copied and nothing else, but when I run the build I get all the xml, xsl, and any other file that is in the resources directory.  am I missing something here or is this a bug with the resources plugin.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration> 
    <outputDirectory>${user.home}/cms/conf</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: BTW I am pretty sure that just adding the includes stanza should have been sufficient but that wasn't working so I added the excludes stanza to see if that would help.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a couple different things causing this. first maven version: the 2.0.2 version fails if the execution stanzas are added to the resources plugin, so I removed it. then I ran into another problem related to the version so I upgraded the version to 3.0.3 and that is when I started getting the files copied over but the excludes was getting ignored. at this point I had forgotten about the execution stanzas so now a few hours later I was re-reading the documentation and saw them and added them again. and all is right with the world